# Is $e^{B}$, where $B$ is a member of the $SU(2)$ matrix algebra, a member of the $SU(2)$ group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quantum-field-theory

I am doing some work in quantum field theory, and I have a question regarding the representation of the $SU(2)$ group. My understanding is that the $SU(2)$ group can be represented as $e^B$, where $B$ is a member of the $su(2)$ algebra. $B$ can be written as $igB^\alpha t_\alpha$, where $t_\alpha$ are the generators. However, how does this exponential expression give a member of the $SU(2)$ group? Expanding it as a Taylor Series, the determinant of $e^B$ is not going to remain $1$. Do I have incorrect reasoning for any part of this explanation?

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of the Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group $G$, that it consists exactly of those matrices $X$ such that $e^{tX} \in G$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. The determinant does remain $1$; why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: Hint: let $f(t) = \det (e^{tB})$. Show that $f' = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318169/determinant-of-matrix-exponential) that
$$\det(\exp\mathbf A)=\exp(\operatorname{tr}\mathbf A)$$
But $\mathbf A\in \mathfrak{su}(2)\implies \operatorname{tr}\mathbf A=0$ which shows that
$$\det(\exp \mathbf A)=1$$
As expected. There is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Lie product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_product_formula) implies that if $\exp t A$, $\exp  t B$ are in a (closed) matrix group for all $t$,  then so is $\exp(A+B)$. That should ease some of your concerns.

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant to the OP's question about the determinant.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Yes, you are right, and the statement was not even correct.  Even corrected, it just eased my concerns. Feel free to downvote.